# How to populate UI from data in a database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, user-interface

I currently have a UI for users to select reminders on Activity A. These reminder attributes are saved in a database, and the reminder is populated into a listview on Activity B. How would I go about selecting a reminder item on the listview on Activity B, grabbing this data from the database, and populating the UI of Activity A with the data that was previously selected.

Is there a standard to do something like this? Should I create the selections as a serialized object to be saved in the database and then use this data? Or should I just save each attribute as a field in the database and have each saved item as a field?

I am pretty new to this stuff, so I am not sure if I should go with a database, shared preference or content provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), which provides a consistent point of access to your database. With a `ContentProvider`, you can take advantage of the [Loader framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) (also available via the Support Library), [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), and [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) to keep your `ListView` in sync with your database.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the response. Ill dive in.